# yii friendly url for modules does not work

Tags: yii

I created a modules called **calculator** and am trying to create the freindly url for it.

here is my code

```
'<action:(calc1|calc2|calc3)>' => '/calculator/<action>',
```

the view files are in

```
modules/calculator/view/default/pages/calc2.php
```

when i type in my address bar

```
localhost/dev/cal2
```

i get this error

```
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "calculator/calc2".
```

in my controller i have this

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function actions() {
       return array(
            'page' => array('class' => 'CViewAction'),
        );
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

the default page shows when i go to `http://localhost/dev/calculator` but the inner pages in the modules doesn't.

here is my regex

```
'<view:(about|terms|faq|privacy)>' => 'site/page',
'<action:(contact|login|logout)>' => 'site/<action>',
'<fileName:(calc1|calc2|calc3)>' => '/calculator/default/page/view/<fileName>',
'<action:(registration|create)>' => 'user/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to include the name of the controller: `/calculator/default/<action>`

Comment: now it says `The system is unable to find the requested action "calc2".` @topher

Comment: Please post your whole `urlManager`-setup please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `page` action your urls should resolve to `/<module>/<controller>/page/view/<fileName>` where `fileName` is `calc1`, `calc2` etc. Therefore in your case your rules should be:

```
'<fileName:(calc1|calc2|calc3)>' => '/calculator/default/page/view/<fileName>',
```

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/

Comment: Of course - I think you have two problems. First you did not implement correct actions to your controller and second your view templates are not in correct folder or your urls in url manage is incorrect.

Comment: It isn't advised. You will end up adding business logic to views instead of controllers. If you need to pass in parameters to the views you should define them as separate actions as in @Jurik's answer with the logic before the render calls.

Comment: @Jurik all my files are in `modules/calculator/view/default/pages/` I made the changes as what @topher suggested. it works now. BUT now `domain/dev/calculator` doesn't work. it doesnt show the default index.php in `view/default/`

Comment: Do you still have the `actionIndex` function in your controller? What error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define your action in your calculator controller:

```
class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCalc1()
    {
        $this->render('calc1');
    }

    public function actionCalc2()
    {
        $this->render('calc2');
    }

    public function actionCalc3()
    {
        $this->render('calc3');
    }
}
```

Of course you've to change your view paths and then you should see something when you type into your browser `<your domain>/calculator/calc2`.

Comment: added `  public function actionLoanCalculator()
    {
        $this->render('loan-calculator');
    }` into my DefaultController and `domain/LoanCalculator` still doesn't work

Comment: I guess the guy who down voted this answer does not know Yii or does not know how to handle controller/action based frameworks correct.

Comment: I guess that someone down voted because the problem is in route definition, not in missing actions